# Function fails in IE7, but works in all modern browsers. How can it be fixed?

Tags: javascript, function, internet-explorer-7

I have this JavaScript code to format a number for US dollars that was given many thumbs up on Stackoverflow. It works well in the latest web browsers, but it causes the JavaScript to fail in IE7. I was trying to use a function that didn't require JQuery because the rest of this project isn't using it:

```
 function formatDollar(num) {
     var p = num.toFixed(2).split(".");
     return "$" + p[0].split("").reverse().reduce(function(acc, num, i, orig) {
         return  num + (i && !(i % 3) ? "," : "") + acc;
     }, "") + "." + p[1];
 }
```

IE7 to the user simply says "Error on Page". In debugging mode on IE7 is complains it isn't an expected Object for the form being submitted on the On Click line. If I remove the above function and have it pass the numbers without formatting it works in IE7. It also complains about the line that starts with the first "return". I have eliminated everything else from the JavaScript and this function is the culprit it appears.

Comment: Having since tested this more extensively, I believe this function has a bug unrelated to IE7. When it displays negative dollar amounts such as -100.00 it's displayed as $-,100.0 instead of $-100.00. Perhaps the author is this didn't realize there would be negative dollar amounts that need to be displayed.

Although I didn't want to use JQuery, is there a much better option to do this with JQuery that is matured code? Thanks!

Comment: I imagine that's a matter for discussion on the question this code was originally posted to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `reduce` function is only available in JavaScript 1.8 (ECMAScript 5) and above, which IE7 does not implement. If you're not already using any libraries that provide its functionality cross-browser, it can be implemented thus:

```
if (!Array.prototype.reduce) {  
  Array.prototype.reduce = function reduce(accumulator){  
    if (this===null || this===undefined) throw new TypeError("Object is null or undefined");  
    var i = 0, l = this.length >> 0, curr;  

    if(typeof accumulator !== "function") // ES5 : "If IsCallable(callbackfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception."  
      throw new TypeError("First argument is not callable");  

    if(arguments.length < 2) {  
      if (l === 0) throw new TypeError("Array length is 0 and no second argument");  
      curr = this[0];  
      i = 1; // start accumulating at the second element  
    }  
    else  
      curr = arguments[1];  

    while (i < l) {  
      if(i in this) curr = accumulator.call(undefined, curr, this[i], i, this);  
      ++i;  
    }  

    return curr;  
  };  
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind not using the simplified syntax of `reduce`, just replace it in your function with an equivalent loop (e.g. the `while` loop above, or a `for` varient).

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#section_14)

Comment: Thanks! I have included this code to execute first and it worked in IE7 like a charm! It also worked in modern browsers.